# Libgdx - SpriteBatch alpha not working

Tags: android, libgdx

```
game.batch.setColor(1,1,1,alpha)
```

I am extending Game and implementing Screen. So the game class is the class passed to the Game screen. Then in Game Screen when you hit the wall I am doing this:

```
alpha -= delta;
if (alpha <= 0) {
     alpha = 0;
}
game.batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, alpha);
if (alpha == 0) {
     restartGame();
}
```

It works normally if I manually change transperency for each sprite. But it seems like the .setColor does not even work for SpriteBatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sprite.draw(batch)`, it ignores whatever color the batch is set to and uses the color of the Sprite. If you want to fade every one of your sprites, you must change the alpha of every one of your sprites.

Comment: Oh well this is a quite a hassle. Last time I manually faded everything when I changed screens. So I though I could just set the batch color. Oh well...

Comment: I believe you can use batch.draw(...) instead of sprite.draw(batch). I think that will work instead.

Comment: Yes, but then you might as well use TextureRegions since you must also specify posirion, rotation, and size for that method.